# Bag & Tuple Schema in Pig

Tags: hadoop, tuples, schema, apache-pig, cloudera

I was trying to specify the schema for some data i'm trying to load using the JsonLoader, the data i want to upload is in the format

```
Features:["Speedy","New","Automatic",..]
```

For each record, the number of features is not fixed it can be different.I was representing this in the schema as :

```
Features: bag{a: tuple(t:chararray)}
```

However it isn't working. Can someone please help me out with the correct syntax and point out where i'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Field name specification is unnecessary because you have simple array without any field names. Try this:

```
a = load 'a.json' using JsonLoader('value:int,feature:{(chararray)}');
```

Json file:

```
{"value":1, "feature":[1, 2, 3] }
{"value":2, "feature":[2,3,4]}
{"value":3, "feature":[12,13,14]}
{"value":4, "feature":[2]}
```

Output:

```
(1,{(1),(2),(3)})
(2,{(2),(3),(4)})
(3,{(12),(13),(14)})
(4,{(2)})
```